# how to seperate date and time from datetime variable

Tags: sas

Here is my question ,please drop your answers, thanks in advance.

`Actual_DT=23MAY16:07:21:00` and it is in `DATETIME16. format.`
how can i separate `date` and `time` and create new variables `visit_date` and `visit_time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `datepart` and `timepart` functions.

```
data result;
  actual_dt = "23MAY16:07:21:00"dt;
  visit_date = datepart(actual_dt);
  visit_time = timepart(actual_dt);

  format visit_date ddmmyy10. visit_time time8.;
run;
```

Comment: Check if the answer meets your expectations. Now, this question is still active.